# How to check which element has .is-active class

Tags: angular, element

How can I check which one of two tabs has `.is-active` class with Angular 2? I have the following code in my TabsComponent component:

```
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
    <a href="#expense" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Expense</a>
    <a href="#income" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Income</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should use data binding to access the class. Based on your example a viable option is as follows: `<a href ... [(class.is-active)]="classIsActive">Expense</a>` Your tracking variable `classIsActive` will update once the class is changed from an external trigger, thanks to Angular2's two-way binding.

Another option is to use `elementref` to access the underlying DOM of the component.